# react-native app has been started, adding navigation now

Tags: javascript, android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I'm building my first react-native app and I've successfully created my Login Screen and a login form component (as well as a blank splash screen Splash.js that I'm wanting to navigate to)

So the form is fully functional with a touchableOpacity instance as a button. I'm not trying to verify the username and password right now but i want my login touchableOpacity to navigate to a splash screen.

I just successfully installed `react-navigation, react-navigation-stack and react-native-gesture-handler` but  I just did the navigation imports on my App.js file and now my login page comes up with the error `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')`

So now is as good a time as any to fully get my navigation issues under control so that I don't have to tackle it later. What exactly am i doing wrong here and how can I rectify this so my loginForm touchable navigates to my splash screen?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Splash from './Splash';
import Login from './src/components/Login/Login';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: Login},
  Dash: {screen: Splash}
});


export default class MMH_App_Final extends Component{
  render() {
    const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
    return(
      <Login />
    );
  }
}
```

Login.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, Image,  View, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';
import LoginForm from './LoginForm';

export default class Login extends Component{
  render() {
    return(
      <KeyboardAvoidingView behavior="padding" style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.logoContainer}>
          <Image 
            style={styles.logo}
            source={require('../../images/FINAL_MYMD_LOGO-1024x250.png')}
          />
          <Text>
            An App for Health And Wellness
          </Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.formContainer}>
          <LoginForm />
        </View>
      </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
  }
}
```

LoginForm.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {StyleSheet, View, TextInput, Text, TouchableOpacity, StatusBar} from 'react-native';

    export default class LoginForm extends Component {
        render() {
            const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
            return (
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <StatusBar 
                        barStyle="light-content"
                    />
                    <TextInput 
                        placeholder="Email"
                        placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
                        returnKeyType="next"
                        onSubmitEditing={() => this.passwordInput.focus()}
                        keyboardType="email-address"
                        autoCapitalize="none"
                        autoCorrect={false}
                        style={styles.input}
                    />
                    <TextInput 
                        placeholder="Password"
                        placeholderTextColor="rgba(255,255,255,0.7)"
                        returnKeyType="go"
                        secureTextEntry
                        style={styles.input}
                        ref={(input) => this.passwordInput = input}
                    />

                    <TouchableOpacity 
                        onPress={() => navigate('Splash')} 
                        style={styles.buttonContainer}>

                        <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
                            LOGIN
                        </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>

                </View>
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things wrong in the code first thing is in `App.js` you are creating an `AppContainer` using `createAppContainer` which will pass the navigation prop down all the screen you have and also is also responsible for switching the active screen, so rather than returning you `LoginScreen` you should return the `AppNavigator`.

App.js

```
export default class MMH_App_Final extends Component{
  render() {
    const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
    return(
      <App />
    );
  }
}
```

Now you should be able to access the navigation prop in your screen, but since you also have `LoginForm` inside `LoginScreen` the navigation prop will not be passed from `LoginScreen` to `LoginForm` so you will either have to manually pass it to like so:

```
<LoginForm navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
```

OR

you could use a handy HOC provided by `react-navigation` called `withNavigation` this will pass the navigation props to any component.

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class LoginForm extends Component {
  render() {
    return (/*Components*/);
  }
}

export default withNavigation(LoginForm);
```

Comment: So how will I handle making the login screen the first screen the app directs to?

Comment: You can use the `initialRouteName` to handle that [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/routers.html#custom-navigation-actions)

Comment: Also don't use `createAppContainer` inside render

Answer (score 0):

render the App. Actually Containers are responsible for managing your app state and linking your top-level navigator to the app environment.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Splash from './Splash';
import Login from './src/components/Login/Login';
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation';
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';

const MainNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: Login},
  Dash: {screen: Splash}
});


export default class MMH_App_Final extends Component{
  render() {
    const App = createAppContainer(MainNavigator);
    return(
      <App/>
    );
  }
}
```